# Unable to load cakephp index.php file initially in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cakephp, web-development-server

Unable to load Cakephp index.php file initially in the browser. I have downloaded all the latest Cakephp-3.1.1 version from Github and placed it in my root folder. Initially when I tried loading it on browser nothing is coming then I checked in the console so it showed :

> ERROR-1:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBadgeText' of
>   undefined
>   'chrome-extension://gnniaejgfdelaafcjopndjdebjfnkljf/app.js:1'
>
> ERROR-2:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of
>   500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost/cakework/cake/

I tried changing permissions to 777 to whole www folder which is my root.

Comment: Follow the [installation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html) guide and install using composer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I did using composer also but same problem !

Comment: "ERROR-1" is from a chrome extension so nothing to do with cakephp. As for "ERROR-2" check your webserver's error log or cake's error logs which would be under <your app>/logs/error.log